# Can I put a workflow or or build a process builder flow around the GroupMember object?

Tags: trigger, workflow, process-builder, public-group

I am trying to send an email to a single person every time someone gets added to or is removed from a Public Group. Can I do this via standard workflow or using the process builder?

If no, can this be done using a trigger? Want to avoid writing a trigger if there is an easier solution!

Comment: This seems like the sort of question you should just check in the UI yourself.

Comment: @Adrian are you saying this "should be" a feature addition or there is somewhere in the UI to set this up?